# CORS at Hostinger Web host

Tags: angular, cors, web-hosting

i have a premium web hosting at Hostinger and I'm trying to make a request to an external API, but it is blocked by CORS. I could access the endpoint from my localhost through a proxy.config file and through postman web too

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
 Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Accept, Accept-  Version,  Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, x-api-key, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization"
 Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "*"
</IfModule>
```

This is the OPTIONS request:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWVbT.png)

This is the POST request:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JA7K.png)

Comment: Your .htaccess file seems to look good to allow CORS requests. Sometimes the server config or the external API may have additional restrictions in place that prevent CORS requests. You said that you were able to access the API through a proxy.config file on your localhost. Try setting up a proxy server on your web hosting server to forward the requests to the external API.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi, do you know how do that in hostinger? ty